Can not change resolution in Enhanced session mode with Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine
On Windows 11 (Hyper-V) I installed the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS image using Quick Create function.
When enabling Enhanced session, I can login and everything (well, what I tried) works, except changing the resolution/screen size.
The Display Settings dialog only shows the current resolution (which is 1364x768) and does not allow changing it. Neither does xrandr.
Also, resizing the VM window does not work. Enabling full screen shows the 1364x768 content with big black borders.
I tried the grub changes and set-vmvideo in PowerShell, as suggested elsewhere, but those make no change.
Is there a way to make this work? Either set a single custom resolution or allow dynamic resizing (like Windows guests)?
PS: This blog suggests, Enhanced Session Mode with Dynamic desktop resizing is supported.

generally with virtualization systems, the resolution of the virtual monitor is controlled by the virtualization provider or its client. if you want dynamic sizing ("fit vm to window", "fit window to vm"), you usually have to the virtualization platforms guest extensions package.

@FrankThomas The Quick Create uses a customized image with all the guest extensions (more or less) preconfigured.

The resolution is asked by the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Connection window first time it is opened. So:

close the VMC window (the VM will continue to run)
reopen it (from the Hyper-V Manager, by selecting the desired VM and then Connect...)
in the new VMC window, it will pop up a dialog asking for the screen resolution

Dynamic resizing OTOH does not seem to work.
